# Exposing a Web service which can support both SOAP 1.1 & SOAP 1.2 Clients

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, jax-ws, ws-security

Currently, I am using annotations to specify the binding type, there by specifically indicating that my web service should use SOAP 1.2, but i want to modify my web service to accept both SOAP 1.1 and SOAP 1.2 requests.

Could you please help if there is a way to do that?

```
@WebService
    public interface ExternalService {
        @WebMethod
        public WebTx getTxByTxRefNum(@WebParam(name="txRefNumber") String txRefNumber,
                @WebParam(name="applicationName") String applicationName);
    }

@WebService(endpointInterface = "com.abc.cde.service.ExternalService", serviceName ="ExternalService")
@BindingType(value = SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)
@WSDLDocumentation(value="ABC SOAP 1.2 Services for External Applications", placement = WSDLDocumentation.Placement.TOP)
public class ExternalServiceImpl implements ExternalService {

    @Autowired
    private TxService txService = null;

    public WebTx getTxByTxRefNum(String txRefNumber, String applicationName) {
        try {
            ---
            ---
            Tx tx = this.txService.getTransactionByTxRefNum(txRefNumber, applicationName);
        } catch(RuntimeException runtimeException) {
            ---
            ----
            ---
        }
    }
}

<bean id="externalService" class="com.abc.cde.service.ExternalServiceImpl"/>

<jaxws:endpoint id="ExternalService" implementor="#externalService" address="/ExternalService">
         <jaxws:inInterceptors>
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.saaj.SAAJInInterceptor" />
            <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <map>
                        <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken" />
                        <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText" />
                        <entry key="passwordCallbackRef">
                            <ref bean="serverPasswordCallback" />
                        </entry>
                    </map>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
            <!-- <ref bean="logInbound" />
            <ref bean="logOutbound" /> -->
          </jaxws:inInterceptors>
    </jaxws:endpoint>
```

Answer (score 1):

In CXF, it's automatic.   An endpoint exposed via SOAP 1.2 will also handle 1.1 requests and will automatically respond with a 1.1 response.

Comment: I also thought the same. But it is not working. If I remove @BindingType(value = SOAP12HTTP_BINDING),service can handle SOAP 1.1 requests, but it cannot handle SOAP 1.2 requests.